# Regex matching decimal formatted number, with checks for count of numbers before and after decimal point

Tags: java, regex, validation

I may have a decimal formats like:

```
"#.#"
"#.##"
"#.00"
"##.###"
"##.000"
"###.###"
"#####.####"
"####.#####"
etc.
```

I want to validate a decimal formatted numbers[0-9] with 1 decimal point.

Additionally, I want to include this checks:

1) Before decimal point, there should be 0 or less or equal then the counted hash tags.

2) After decimal point, there should be 0 or less or equal then the counted hash tags.

For example:

Format definition is `"##.###"`, and for this format, valid format numbers are those that have in this case, before decimal point, a 0 or less or equal than 2 numbers, 1 dot, and a 0 or less or equal than 3 numbers.
Valid numbers are:

```
"1",
"12",
"12.3",
"12.34",
"12.345",
```

Invalid numbers are:

```
"1.3456", -- because there are 4 digits after decimal point
"12.34567", -- because there are 5 digits after decimal point
"123.3", -- because there are 3 digits before decimal point
"123.3454", -- because there are 3 digits before decimal point and 4 digits after decimal point
```

UPDATE:

Test

```
format: ###.###
    1. 12.34 -> result: matches; expected: matches
    2. 123.456 -> result: matches; expected: matches
    3. 123.4567 -> result: matches; expected: not matches
    4. 1234.567 -> result: not matches; expected: not matches
    5. 1234.5678 -> result: not matches; expected: not matches
```

Case 3. fails.

Code for testing patterns and numbers:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {

        double[] initialValues = {
            12.34,
            123.456,
            123.4567,
            1234.567,
            1234.5678,

            0,
            1,
            12,
            123,

            0.1,
            0.123,
            123.0,

            1.2,
            1.23,
            1.234,

            1.2,
            12.3,
            123.4,

            123456.678,
            12345.6789,

            1.23456789
        };

        String[] decimalFormats = {
            "###.###",

            "#.#",
            "#.##",
            "#.###",

            "#.#",
            "##.#",
            "###.#",

            "###.###",
            "#####.#####"
        };
        new Main().testParsingNumber(initialValues, decimalFormats);
    }

    public void testParsingNumber(double[] initialValues, String[] decimalFormats) throws ParseException {
        for (String decimalFormat : decimalFormats) {
            System.out.println(decimalFormat);

            for (double initialValue : initialValues) {
                String formattedDecimalNumber = new DecimalFormat(decimalFormat).format(initialValue);
                System.out.println("\t" + initialValue + " -> " + (isValidDecimalNumber(formattedDecimalNumber, decimalFormat) ? "matches" : "not matches"));
            }

            System.out.println("\n");
        }
    }

    public boolean isValidDecimalNumber(String formattedDecimalNumber, String decimalFormat) {
        List<String> digits = Arrays.asList(decimalFormat.split("[.]"));
        int maxNumbersBeforeDecimal = digits.get(0).length();
        int maxNumbersAfterDecimal = digits.get(1).length();

        //[0-9]{1,"+x1+"} => match digit before the decimal point with occurrence 1-x1
        //[0-9]{0,"+x2+"} => match digit after the decimal point 0-x2
        //.{0,1} => match the decimal point

        Pattern regexPattern = Pattern.compile("^[0-9]{1,"+ maxNumbersBeforeDecimal +"}.{0,1}[0-9]{0,"+ maxNumbersAfterDecimal +"}$");
        Matcher matcher = regexPattern.matcher(doubleValue);
        return matcher.matches();
    }
```

Results:

```
###.###
    12.34 -> matches
    123.456 -> matches
    123.4567 -> matches -- This should return false. Not correct! Returns true.
    1234.567 -> not matches -- This should return false. Correct!
    1234.5678 -> not matches -- This should return false. Correct!
    0.0 -> matches
    1.0 -> matches
    12.0 -> matches
    123.0 -> matches
    0.1 -> matches
    0.123 -> matches
    123.0 -> matches
    1.2 -> matches
    1.23 -> matches
    1.234 -> matches
    1.2 -> matches
    12.3 -> matches
    123.4 -> matches
    123456.678 -> not matches 
    12345.6789 -> not matches
    1.23456789 -> matches  -- Not correct


#.#
    12.34 -> not matches
    123.456 -> not matches
    123.4567 -> not matches
    1234.567 -> not matches
    1234.5678 -> not matches
    0.0 -> matches
    1.0 -> matches
    12.0 -> matches  -- Not correct
    123.0 -> matches  -- Not correct
    0.1 -> matches
    0.123 -> matches  -- Not correct
    123.0 -> matches  -- Not correct
    1.2 -> matches 
    1.23 -> matches  -- Not correct
    1.234 -> matches  -- Not correct
    1.2 -> matches
    12.3 -> not matches 
    123.4 -> not matches
    123456.678 -> not matches
    12345.6789 -> not matches
    1.23456789 -> matches  -- Not correct


#.##
    12.34 -> not matches
    123.456 -> not matches
    123.4567 -> not matches
    1234.567 -> not matches
    1234.5678 -> not matches
    0.0 -> matches
    1.0 -> matches
    12.0 -> matches
    123.0 -> matches
    0.1 -> matches
    0.123 -> matches
    123.0 -> matches
    1.2 -> matches
    1.23 -> matches
    1.234 -> matches
    1.2 -> matches
    12.3 -> not matches
    123.4 -> not matches
    123456.678 -> not matches
    12345.6789 -> not matches
    1.23456789 -> matches


#.###
    12.34 -> not matches
    123.456 -> not matches
    123.4567 -> not matches
    1234.567 -> not matches
    1234.5678 -> not matches
    0.0 -> matches
    1.0 -> matches
    12.0 -> matches
    123.0 -> matches
    0.1 -> matches
    0.123 -> matches
    123.0 -> matches
    1.2 -> matches
    1.23 -> matches
    1.234 -> matches
    1.2 -> matches
    12.3 -> not matches
    123.4 -> not matches
    123456.678 -> not matches
    12345.6789 -> not matches
    1.23456789 -> matches


#.#
    12.34 -> not matches
    123.456 -> not matches
    123.4567 -> not matches
    1234.567 -> not matches
    1234.5678 -> not matches
    0.0 -> matches
    1.0 -> matches
    12.0 -> matches
    123.0 -> matches
    0.1 -> matches
    0.123 -> matches
    123.0 -> matches
    1.2 -> matches
    1.23 -> matches
    1.234 -> matches
    1.2 -> matches
    12.3 -> not matches
    123.4 -> not matches
    123456.678 -> not matches
    12345.6789 -> not matches
    1.23456789 -> matches


##.#
    12.34 -> matches
    123.456 -> not matches
    123.4567 -> not matches
    1234.567 -> not matches
    1234.5678 -> not matches
    0.0 -> matches
    1.0 -> matches
    12.0 -> matches
    123.0 -> matches
    0.1 -> matches
    0.123 -> matches
    123.0 -> matches
    1.2 -> matches
    1.23 -> matches
    1.234 -> matches
    1.2 -> matches
    12.3 -> matches
    123.4 -> not matches
    123456.678 -> not matches
    12345.6789 -> not matches
    1.23456789 -> matches


###.#
    12.34 -> matches
    123.456 -> matches
    123.4567 -> matches
    1234.567 -> not matches
    1234.5678 -> not matches
    0.0 -> matches
    1.0 -> matches
    12.0 -> matches
    123.0 -> matches
    0.1 -> matches
    0.123 -> matches
    123.0 -> matches
    1.2 -> matches
    1.23 -> matches
    1.234 -> matches
    1.2 -> matches
    12.3 -> matches
    123.4 -> matches
    123456.678 -> not matches
    12345.6789 -> not matches
    1.23456789 -> matches


###.###
    12.34 -> matches
    123.456 -> matches
    123.4567 -> matches
    1234.567 -> not matches
    1234.5678 -> not matches
    0.0 -> matches
    1.0 -> matches
    12.0 -> matches
    123.0 -> matches
    0.1 -> matches
    0.123 -> matches
    123.0 -> matches
    1.2 -> matches
    1.23 -> matches
    1.234 -> matches
    1.2 -> matches
    12.3 -> matches
    123.4 -> matches
    123456.678 -> not matches
    12345.6789 -> not matches
    1.23456789 -> matches


#####.#####
    12.34 -> matches
    123.456 -> matches
    123.4567 -> matches
    1234.567 -> matches
    1234.5678 -> matches
    0.0 -> matches
    1.0 -> matches
    12.0 -> matches
    123.0 -> matches
    0.1 -> matches
    0.123 -> matches
    123.0 -> matches
    1.2 -> matches
    1.23 -> matches
    1.234 -> matches
    1.2 -> matches
    12.3 -> matches
    123.4 -> matches
    123456.678 -> not matches
    12345.6789 -> matches
    1.23456789 -> matches
```

Comment: You mean to say that when the input is `#.#`, `1.2` is valid but when the input becomes `#.##`, the number `1.2` becomes invalid?

Comment: It will be valid, because that pattern has two hash tags after decimal point, and your value has only 1, so it will be balid.

Comment: Wouldn't `new DecimalFormat(format).parse(input)` be a more effective way to validate the input? (rather than converting the format to an equivalent regex first and then testing that regex on the input)

Comment: Parse the format definition and take length of before dot and after dot,then write your reg ex just like [1-9]{,lengthBeforeDot}.[1-9]{,lengthAfterDot}

Comment: @ernest_k Actually, that's not effective enough for my case, since I will need to do some more validation, which I did not mention as a part of this ticket - is not a topic.

Comment: For `##.###` format validation, OP may use: `^(?:\d+|\d{1,2}\.\d{1,3})$`

Comment: Is there a difference between `"#.##"` and `"#.00"` formats?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my solution using regex :

```
    String x = "###.###";
    List<String> s = Arrays.asList(x.split("[.]"));
    int x1 = s.get(0).length();
    int x2 = s.get(1).length();

    //[0-9]{1,"+x1+"} => match digit before the decimal point with occurrence 1-x1
    //[0-9]{0,"+x2+"} => match digit after the decimal point 0-x2
    //.{0,1} => match the decimal point
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[0-9]{1,"+x1+"}.{0,1}[0-9]{0,"+x2+"}$");

    Matcher matcher = p.matcher("123.33");
    System.out.println(matcher.matches());//true
```

Comment: Of course, `1111.111` return false if you have a format like  "###.###". the regex pattern `[0-9]{1,3}` limit the occurrence of the number to 3. And I see `true` when I test it.Have you tried?

Comment: I guess it is not working because you format the `initialValue`. So for the `initialValue=123.4567` the `formattedDecimalNumber=123.457` and then it pass the test with the pattern '###.###'. Calling the `isValidDecimalNumber` like this `isValidDecimalNumber(String.valueOf(initialValue), decimalFormat)`  resolve the issue.